# Association(Junction) tables using mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, many-to-many

I have two tables which are :

- user table : user_id, name
- course table : course_id, content

**user table**

```
-------------------------
| user_id | name        |
-------------------------
| 1       | x           |
-------------------------
| 2       | y           |
-------------------------
```

**course table**

```
------------------------------
| course_id | content        |
------------------------------
| 1         | a              |
------------------------------
| 2         | b              |
------------------------------
| 3         | c              |
------------------------------
```

How would I be able to associate each row from the user table with all the rows in the course table?

I want to associate shown as below:

```
----------------------------------------
| user_id | name | course_id | content |
----------------------------------------
| 1       | x    | 1         | a       |
----------------------------------------
| 1       | x    | 2         | b       |
----------------------------------------
| 1       | x    | 3         | c       |
----------------------------------------
| 2       | y    | 1         | a       |
----------------------------------------
| 2       | y    | 2         | b       |
----------------------------------------
| 2       | y    | 3         | c       |
----------------------------------------
```

I have created an association(junction) table user_course: user_id and course_id but don't know how to populate it

**Code I am using for inserting is shown below:**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO user_course ( user_id, course_id ) VALUES ( :user_id, :course_id )";
$pdo_statement = $pdo_conn->prepare( $query );
$result = $pdo_statement->execute( array( ':user_id'=> $last_insert_id , ':course_id'=> $ids ) );
```

> Note: $last_insert_id is the user registered but how to get all the
>   course ids in $ids

Please suggest some ways to achieve it?

Comment: Try a many-to-many and see? It seems like you've already figured it out, so you should do some attempts and come back if you run into some issue.

Comment: That code tries to store the text `SELECT id FROM course` in the `vid`-column. Not sure what you're actually trying to do with this code. If you have issues with your code, please show us _all_ the relevant code together with the proper table definitions. You should also explain what your actual issue is. Which part are you actually struggling with? You say _"Output I am getting"_ but there's no code here that indicates you fetching anything from the database or outputting anything.

Comment: I would suggest there is no need to create the "associate" table.  When you list the content, you'll have an object with all the courses in it.  Should any courses be attempted by the user, then you could populate a table showing the user_id and course_id, but it would be of no obvious benefit to duplicate the content from the course table.

Comment: What do you want to add in User_Course table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use cross join to get the result you are looking for:

```
INSERT INTO user_course
SELECT * FROM user CROSS JOIN course;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [INSERT .. SELECT statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) to attach all existed courses to a user.

For example (SQL):

```
INSERT INTO user_course (user_id, course_id) 
SELECT FROM <user_id>, course_id FROM course
```

For example (PHP):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO user_course (user_id, course_id) SELECT :user_id, course_id FROM course";
$pdo_statement = $pdo_conn->prepare($query);
$result = $pdo_statement->execute(array(':user_id'=> $last_insert_id));
```

If you want to attach all courses to all users you can use the following query

```
INSERT INTO user_course (user_id, course_id) 
SELECT FROM user.user_id, course.course_id FROM user, course
```

Comment: `SELECT FROM :user_id` where is this syntax documented? I don't think it works.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel oh. It's the mistake. I fixed it and updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Thats correct.

If any users can be registered in any course, you can create a table called users_courses, that permits a N:N relationship, using the schema exemplified by you.

This way, you allow a user to have no course, one course or even all courses.

Comment: @Peace Do you want a script to relate all users with all courses?

Comment: To relate all users to all courses on your table you can try this: ```INSERT INTO users_courses SELECT user_id, course_id FROM user, course;```

Comment: @Peace - Instead of asking us to do all your work for you, you need to actually make some attempts before asking. SO isn't a free coding service. This question basically just turned to a "gimme code"-question. You've already mentioned a way you can do it so test it out.

Answer (score 0):

A many:many table normally needs 2 columns -- the ids into the two tables that it is associating.  Do not redundantly include names, etc., that already exist in the two tables.

It also needs (in your example)

```
PRIMARY KEY(user_id, course_id),
INDEX(course_id, user_id)
```

These let you efficiently map from users to courses and vice versa.

I discuss such tables further in [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the result - combined the use of **insert...select** with **cross join**

Here is the code for the junction table :

```
$id = lastInsertId;
$query = "INSERT INTO user_course ( user_id, course_id ) ( SELECT A.user_id, B.course_id FROM user A CROSS JOIN course B WHERE A.user_id = $id)";
```

Comment: I think this is related to @rika answer, i think his answer must be accepted being awarded the bounty